# Is it possible to clip an object's alpha to another object in the viewport?

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes, transparency, npr

I'm trying to find a way to recreate an 'alpha clip' effect that 2D art software has. I'm trying to create 3d/2d characters. An example use case would be making a pupil/iris object, then clipping its alpha to an eyeball object. I would also want to see the result in the viewport while working. I am using Eevee but I'll hear cycles answers.

All of the examples are a cylinder alpha clipped inside a cube.

The first method I tried was using the compositor to mix them. This works, but the render layers node does not work in the viewport compositor. Maybe there is a way to work around that limitation?

[image: Cylinder intersecting a cube. The cube's alpha replaces the cylinder's alpha]

The second method I tried was converting objects into grease pencil and using the layer mask functionality. This works, but would remove any materials I had on the objects. This will probably be the method I end up using if there is no better solution.

[image: Grease pencil versions of the cylinder intersecting a cube. The cylinder's color projects onto the cube]

My *Ideal* solution would be to drive the factor of a mix shader node *with the alpha of another object within the shader editor*. Is this possible? I do not know how this could be done, so I just put an empty node group in the picture. Any insight would be useful.

[image: Material node tree of another cylinder connected to a mix shader node, which has its factor driven by an empty node group]

There is the option to code shapes using nodes/SDFs in shader editor, apply that material to the cube, and have it projected in some manner. I'm really only looking for clipping geometry to geometry though. A Boolean modifier would be too slow. I'll probably have to compromise, but at least I asked.

I notice there's a difference between the compositor result (method 1) and the grease pencil result (method 2): In method 1, the cylinder appears on top of the cube no matter if the cube obstructs it. I do not mind which behavior your solution follows. Thanks for reading.